# Calculate average of 3 dimensional array in R

Tags: arrays, r

I am extracting the coefficients from 4 `pls` models and taking an average. I'd like to create a new model, as a copy from one of the 4, and replace the coefficients with the average to predict new data. I know the correct set up with cross-validation could do this for me, but I'd like to just hack it for now. My problem happens when I try to predict, the coefficients object dimensions are incorrect.

In this example I extract four arrays(`m#_reg_coef`) with dimensions of `[1:151, 1, 1:21]`. There are 151 x variables, and 21 components or latent variables for these pls models. After my averaging with my code below I get a single data frame of `[1:151, 1:21]`.... how can I take the average of the four arrays while maintaining the correct dimensions?... I am looking to average the four arrays to an output that has the dimensions of `[1:151, 1, 1:21]`

```
library(abind)

arr = abind(m1_reg_cof,m2_reg_cof, m3_reg_cof, m4_reg_cof, along = 2)
abds <- apply( arr,  c(1,3), mean)

dim(abds)
[1] 151  21

new_pls_model<-old_pls_model
new_pls_model$coefficients<-abds

test_predicted_1 <- predict(New_plsr_model, ncomp = 21, newdata = test_data_1)
```

error

```
Error in object$coefficients[, , ncomp, drop = FALSE] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Comment: Well, there is a misspelling. Is it that simple?

Comment: Are you looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058978/mean-on-the-third-dimension-in-r  ? `apply(arr, c(1,2), mean)` instead of `c(1,3)`

Comment: @42 I'm not sure what you mean by "secondary", would that refer to something external validation? I am attempting to test new data(externally validate) with the same type of model: partial least squares (PLS), the only difference is I'd like to create my own regression coefficients from the average of four previously created models...does that answer your question?

Comment: @thelatemail... No `apply(arr, c(1,2), mean)` gives a data frame of `[1:152,1:4]`

Comment: have you tried simply reshaping abds; e.g., `abds2 <- array(abds, dim = c(dim(abds)[1], 1, dim(abds)[2]))`

Comment: It answered the question I deleted within a minute or so, but doesn't answer the question I left up.

Comment: @ChrisHolbrook your suggestion worked to reshape, but I am not an array or matrix manipulation expert so I am left wondering if am I averaging incorrectly when my output is in different dimensions?

Comment: to check the accuracy, you might want to run it on a simplified sample data set and check results. If you look at it step by step it should be straight forward though. First, your `apply` call essentially says "return the mean over the 1st and 3rd dimensions of the input array" which will return a matrix with rows corresponding to the 1st dim of `arr` and cols corresponding to the 3rd dim of `arr`. The second part (reshape) works by virtue of how arrays are filled (last dim filled before first dim). In your case, it's simply moving each column to it's own third dim.

Comment: another simple way to calculate element-wise means over multiple arrays is to use base math operators, which are element-wise. E.g., `(m1_reg_cof + m2_reg_cof + m3_reg_cof + m4_reg_cof) / 4`. But this does lack convenience features and automation of functions like `mean()`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment by Chris Holbrook, this is the answer that worked for me.

```
library(abind)

#bind the four arrays into one array
arr = abind(m1_reg_cof,m2_reg_cof, m3_reg_cof, m4_reg_cof, along = 2)
dim(arr)
[1] 151   4  21

#average the four
abds <- apply( arr,  c(1,3), mean)
dim(abds)
[1] 151  21

#rehsape the output to match original
abds2 <- array(abds, dim = c(dim(abds)[1], 1, dim(abds)[2]))
dim(abds2)
[1] 151   1  21
```

Add attributes...the dimensional names also need to be the same length as the original

```
#none of the names changed so I can just copy them
dimnames(abds2) <- dimnames(PLSR_model_1$coefficients)

#copy the model
New_plsr_model <- PLSR_model_1

#replace the coefficients
New_plsr_model$coefficients <- (abds2)

#Predict the values of new observations (not seen in the training set)
test_predicted_1 <- predict(New_plsr_model, ncomp = 21, newdata = test_data_1)
```

Success!